# Как склоняется Форт-Холаберд?

Tags: склонение

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как склоняется название американской военной базы Форт-Холаберд и склоняется ли оно вообще? Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Форт-Холабёрд, из Форт-Холабёрда, к Форт-Холабёрду и т.д.

Но есть написание без дефиса, когда имеется в виду крепость, тогда склоняется первое слово: Форт  Холабёрд, из форта Холабёрд, к форту Холабёрд и т.д.